# awk + sorting file according to values in the file and write two diffrent files

Tags: awk

I have in file `file_test` values of right eye and left eye
How to separate the `file_test` to `file1` and `file2` by awk in order to write the equal values into `file1` and different values into `file2` as the following example down

`file_test` is:

```
NAME: jim 
LAST NAME: bakker
right eye: >|5|< 
left eye VALUE: >|5|< 
NAME: Jorg 
LAST NAME: mitchel
right eye: >|3|< 
left eye VALUE: >|5|< 
NAME: jimmy  
LAST NAME: kartter
right eye: >|6|< 
left eye VALUE: >|5|< 
NAME: david  
LAST NAME: kann
right eye: >|9|< 
left eye VALUE: >|9|<
```

`file1` should be:

```
NAME: jim  
LAST NAME: bakker
right eye: >|5|< 
left eye VALUE: >|5|< 
NAME: david  
LAST NAME: kann
right eye: >|9|< 
left eye VALUE: >|9|<
```

`file2` should be:

```
NAME: Jorg  
LAST NAME: mitchel
right eye: >|3|< 
left eye VALUE: >|5|< 
NAME: jimmy  
LAST NAME: kartter
right eye: >|6|< 
left eye VALUE: >|5|<
```

Comment: you can close this case I write bash script that sort the first file , but my first target was to do that with awk
THX
yael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use Perl for this:

```
    open my $f, "<", "file_input";
    open my $file1, ">", "file1";
    open my $file2, ">", "file2";
    while (! eof($f)) {
        my $person; $person .= <$f> for (1..4);  # read 4 lines
        my ($right) = ($person =~ /^right.*?(\d+)/m);
        my ($left) = ($person =~ /^left.*?(\d+)/m);
        my $file = ($right == $left) ? $file1 : $file2;
        print $file $person;
    }
    close $f;
    close $file1;
    close $file2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F: '/^NAME:/ && buff {
  say(buff, eyes); buff = null 
  split(null, eyes) # use delete eyes if supported
  }
{ 
  buff = buff ? buff RS $0 : $0
  /eye/ && eyes[$NF]
  }
END { say(buff, eyes) }
func say(b, e) {
  # length(array) is not portable
  print b > (length(e) > 1 ? "file2" : "file1")
  }' file_test
```